# EC2: How can I get the Vpc ID of an Instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am trying to find out the vpc-id of an instance. Can anyone refer to an API that would work this out? Im using the java sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) API is the one you are looking for. It returns the VPC ID of instance.

Comment: I have looked into it. it does not do that. Could you help me find an appropriate `Filter` for it though? Maybe I'm not doing something right.

Answer (score 14):

You can try doing the below one inside the ec2-instance

First you need to find the macid of the instance

`macid=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/)`

and use the macid below

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${macid}/vpc-id`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's boto framework (you don't need to install anything it's already there)

Example:

```
python -c "import boto.utils as u; print u.get_instance_metadata()['network']['interfaces']['macs'].values()[0]['vpc-id']"
```

On Ec2:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-8-90 ~]$ python -c "import boto.utils as u; print u.get_instance_metadata()['network']['interfaces']['macs'].values()[0]['vpc-id']"
vpc-55ff1a123
```

Or if you are not on AWS network, you can use `aws cli` with `describe-instances` and `--query` parameter:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-6fedd222 --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].VpcId'

me@my-PC:~/workspace$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-6fedd222 --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].VpcId'
"vpc-55ff1a123"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can get the vpc id for the aws instances. Use filters DescribeInstancesRequest when invoking the describeInstances() to restrict your result.

```
AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();
DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult = ec2Client.describeInstances();
List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstanceResult.getReservations(); 
for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {    
   for (Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
      System.out.println(instance.getVpcId());    
   } 
}
```